# why two points can't show in the figure (matplotlib)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Figure1 show data points[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7b9r.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7b9r.png):[image]

I drawed the figure by matplotlib in python, but the data points cannot be fully displayed. There are two points not displayed the lower-right corner of the figure.The two coordinates are (-0.6731984257692413, 6.0), (-0.7105983383119769, 7.0).I don't know why.Anyone could help?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
theta = [0.8975979010256552, 2.6927937030769655, 0, -0.6731984257692413, 0.0, -1.7951958020513104, -0.8975979010256552, -1.7951958020513104, -2.6927937030769655, -0.5235987755982988, -0.59839860068377, -0.8975979010256552, -1.1967972013675403, 1.7951958020513104, -0.5609986881410344, -0.59839860068377, -0.6357985132265057, -0.7105983383119769]
r = [1.0, 0.5, 0, 6.0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.5, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 0.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 7.0]
colors = [1.13290242331, 0.81108163706000003, 0, 0.94180655750400011, 0.90356396220000001, 0.946707749135, 1.09650064153, 1.2068422679700002, 1.1150923324999999, 2.4619798379700004, 0.83030335877799999, 0.87957520389799992, 0.872155341769, 0.92537488526299994, 2.70431872671, 1.10024483211, 0.89817718522000012, 1.1547139643100002]

plt.subplot(111,polar=True)
cc=plt.scatter(theta,r,c=colors,cmap=plt.cm.hsv)

cc.set_alpha(0.75)
plt.grid(color='y', alpha=0.8, linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.colorbar()
plt.thetagrids([30])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Anyone could help? Not unless you post your code!

Comment: For some reason automatic scaling is off; set manually `plt.ylim([0,8])` or something similar.

Comment: @Andras Deak Thank you. I do as you said. The problem is solved.Thank you very much. And how to automatic scaling, if 8 is don't know.

Comment: `max(r)` is a good starting point;) I'd set something dynamically, like `ylim([0,max(r)*1.1])`. You should also do some searching on the web, this should either be an already known bug of matplotlib, or it should be filed as a bug now. I suspect the former, though, I just don't have the time right now to investigate.

Comment: @Andras Deak Thank you very much, I use plt.ylim([0, max(r)+1]).

Comment: I couldn't find any issues along these lines, so I [opened a bug report on github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7130). Nice find:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [a bug in matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7130) that [was fixed by March 2019](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7130#issuecomment-549598694). It will probably be fixed in release 3.2.0.

On matplotlib versions that still have the bug a workaround is to specify the axes limits manually:

```
plt.ylim([0, max(r)+1])
```